# Function pointer without arguments types?

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying to declare a function pointer that points to any function that returns the same type. I omitted the arguments types in the pointer declaration to see what error will be generated. But the program was compiled successfully and executed without any issue.

Is this a correct declaration? Shouldn't we specify the arguments types?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void add(int a, int b)
{
    printf("a + b = %d", a + b);
}

void (*pointer)() = &add;

int main()
{
    add(5, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a + b = 10
```

Comment: This is perfectly legal K&R C.

Comment: Sample code does not make sense as a sample.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why is that?

Comment: pointer has not been used in an assignment other than. By not know do not use even an invalid pointer even if it? It has not been the reason why the correct output is obtained at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Empty parentheses within a type name means unspecified arguments. Note that this is an obsolescent feature.

> #### C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §6.11.6 Function declarators
>
> The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter
> type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

Comment: What does it mean by declarators?

Comment: @rullof Something about declaration(opposed to definition), I really don't how to explain it exactly.

Answer (score 6):

`void (*pointer)()` explains function pointed have unspecified number of argument. It is not similar to `void (*pointer)(void)`. So later when you used two arguments that fits successfully according to definition.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you should know here...

**Function declaration:**

```
int myFunction();
```

**Function prototype:**

```
int myFunction(int a, float b);
```

- A `prototype` is a special kind of declaration that describes the number and the types of function parameters.
- A `non-prototype` function declaration doesn't say anything about its parameter.

Example:

```
int myFunction();
```

This `non-prototype` function declaration does not mean that `myFunction` takes no arguments. It means that `myFunction` take an unspecified number of arguments. The compiler simply turns off argument type checking, number of arguments checking and conversion for `myFunction`.

So you can do,

```
int myFunction();   // The non-prototype signature will match a definition for
                    // myFunction with any parameter list.
// This is the function definition... 
int myFunction(int x, float b, double d)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `float` becomes `double` after promotion. You cannot use non-prototype declarations if you use non-fully-promoted argument types.