# compare two binary files using strcmp() in c Language

Tags: c, file, binary, strcmp

Sorry for my bad English first.

I have two binary files.

And I store binary into buffer respectively.

Then I compared two buffer using strcmp().

Result of strcmp() is zero.

So I think two binary is identical.

Open two binary and then checked if there are no differences.

But I can find little difference.

what is the problem?

strcmp() function doesn't proper way to compare binary to binary?

Comment: You are aware of the difference of binary and string. You do note that there ARE differences, though small. What is it that you do not understand?

Comment: Why do you assume that two binary files are identical when you have tested them with a tool made for text and not binary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C function `strcmp` is written to compare strings. In C, strings are `char` pointers or arrays, that end with a null byte (`'\0'`). Therefore, the comparison only goes up to the first null byte.

Example:

File A: `"abcd\0efg"`
File B: `"abcd\0xyz"`

Since both files are equal up to the null byte, the "strings" at these locations are equal, although what comes after may differ. You should use the function `memcmp` instead (<s>see this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcmp.htm)</s>; see examples from [the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/)).

EDIT:
As pointed out by the comment under this answer and as mentioned in the other answer, the man pages of [`strcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) and [`memcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp) are reliable resources to learn about these function from the standard library.

Comment: A better source to know more about `memcmp()` is the man page.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I thought I pointed that out in the second sentence? As for the man page, you are right :)

Comment: Never link to tutorialspoint. It's very bad. Here is a rant about it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55731680/6699433

Comment: Thank you @klutt, I replaced it with another source

Answer (score 2):

You cant compare binary data using string function.

You need to use `memcmp` instead.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html

Comment: But I store binary into the buffer.

Comment: ... and then compare it with string methods.

Comment: You always store something in some buffers. Buffers are not magical