# how check successfully write after invoke fwrite function in C?

Tags: c, fwrite

I find this code in a website:

```
    struct person 
{
    int id;
    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
};
  
int main ()
{
    FILE *outfile;
      
    // open file for writing
    outfile = fopen ("person.dat", "w");
  
    struct person input1 = {1, "rohan", "sharma"};
      
    // write struct to file
    fwrite (&input1, sizeof(struct person), 1, outfile);

     if(fwrite != 0) 
        printf("contents to file written successfully !\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

1. Is line `if(fwrite != 0)`  correct?
2. Does we can compare function name itself(`fwrite`)?
3. What is value of `fwrite` in this case?

Comment: A C compiler can answer all the questions.

Comment: As a matter of interest what is the website

Comment: This code is broken and does not in fact check the success of the write. I suggest taking a look at the man page for `fwrite`.

Comment: I found code Here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/readwrite-structure-file-c/

Comment: `fwrite != 0` is always true.  You need to check the value returned by `fwrite`, not the address of the function itself.

Comment: I'm upvoting this, because I think it's good to call out sites that presents such rubbish code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's definitely not the correct way to do it. The correct way is this:

```
if(fwrite(&input1, sizeof(struct person), 1, outfile)) != 1) {
    /* Error writing */
}
```

But in order to avoid duplicate magic numbers, this would be better:

```
size_t num = 1;
if(fwrite(&input1, sizeof(struct person), num, outfile)) != num) {
```

I find it hard to believe ANY site would publish rubbish code like that. I knew geeksforgeeks isn't very trustworthy, but this was incredibly bad. It's wrong on so many levels.

`if(fwrite != 0)` is a completely pointless check. If `fwrite != 0` would evaluate to false, it would mean that the function call to `fwrite` would fail. The check basically means "Is `fwrite` a null pointer?" And if a library function is a null pointer, then something is REALLY wrong.

`fwrite` returns the number of elements written, which in this case should be one element.

I wrote a [rant about Tutorialspoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55731680/6699433) earlier, but now I need to add geeksforgeeks to my list of resources I recommend to stay far, far away from.